# Calculate year on year Run_time from cumulative Run_time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In SQL Server, I have maintained following details.

| S.No | Vehicle_ID | Start Date | Failed Date | Total Run years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2011-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 | 2015-12-31 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-01-01 | 2019-12-31 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011-01-01 | 2015-12-31 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 2016-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 7 |
| 8 | 3 | 2013-01-01 | 2016-12-31 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 | 2017-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 5 |

I would like to calculate year on year Run_time from cumulative Run_time

Required result like this:

| Year | Run Years |
| --- | --- |
| 2011 | 2 |
| 2012 | 2 |
| 2013 | 3 |
| 2014 | 3 |
| 2015 | 3 |
| 2016 | 3 |
| 2017 | 3 |
| 2018 | 3 |
| 2019 | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2022 | 2 |

1. **Year** column first year is MIN year from **Start Date**
2. **Year** column end year is MAX year from **Failed Date**

Comment: Your desired result not match source data. In source 2022 is not appear

Comment: I think we need more information and I suspect you are using the wrong functions to do some of these calculations.  If you look at row two of the top table the dates are 01/01/2014 - 31/12/2015.  this is two days short of two years but you are saying it is only 1 year.  If you are using DATEDIFF(YEAR,StartDate,FailDate) this will only give you  the year 'ticks'.  You would get 1 year if the dates were 31/12/2014 to 01/01/2015 because the year has ticked over. 
Based on the data in the first table why is 2011 in the second table 2?

Comment: Do you mean you want a table of the years and count of the number of vehicles in service that year.
What have you tried so far.  Have a look at Tally Tables.